# Is it possible to default a placeholder or tabstop with the value of a previous placeholder or tabstop?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I am trying to create a simple TypeScript import snippet like:

```
import * as module from 'module';
```

As long as I want to keep the `as` part the same as the module, the following `body` is fine:

```
"import * as ${1} from '${1:module}';"
```

However, to be even more efficient, I would like to default the `as` name to whatever was imported, but give myself a chance right there to change it if needed.

I tried the following and a few other variants, but none worked and I might be missing something altogether.

```
"import * as ${2:$1} from '${1:module}';"
```

In the above *code*, the placeholder `$2` is simply bypassed and I don't get a chance to update it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is a bug in VSCode's handling of snippets. Textmate shows the expected behavior with your example snippet:

[image]

I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25058) to track this.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I will keep an eye on the issue.